# label exfat filesystem

Tags: lubuntu, filesystem, exfat

I'm running Lubuntu 22.04.
For PS4 I created on an usb-drive with an exfat filesystem; I so not remember if it was with newer exfatprogs or with the older exfat-utils.

Question:

```
sudo dump.exfat /dev/sdc1
exfatprogs version : 1.1.3
-------------- Dump Boot sector region --------------
Volume Length(sectors):                 625139712
FAT Offset(sector offset):              128
FAT Length(sectors):                    19328
Cluster Heap Offset (sector offset):    19456
Cluster Count:                          2441876
Root Cluster (cluster offset):          6
Volume Serial:                          0xe6d20c21
Sector Size Bits:                       9
Sector per Cluster bits:                8

----------------- Dump Root entries -----------------
Volume entry type:                      0x3
Volume label: 
Volume label character count:           0
Bitmap entry type:                      0x81
Bitmap start cluster:                   2
Bitmap size:                            305235
Upcase table entry type:                0x82
Upcase table start cluster:             5
Upcase table size:                      5836

---------------- Show the statistics ----------------
Cluster size:                           131072
Total Clusters:                         2441876
Free Clusters:                          2434069
```

Shows the dump of the filesystem wich I used for creating it.

I want to give the exfat filesystem a label, but I do not know if I have to use `tune.exfat` or `exfatlabel` - or does it not matter which one I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever one does what you want to do. Read the man pages. Since ExFAT (on disk) has to be compatible, either one should work.